# spark-submit command is not working in case of Python file submission

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have tried a lot to submit the Python code using spark-submit. But I am unable to do.

Below are the following application details

1. I have downloaded Apache-Spark for windows.
2. Download the anaconda
3. I have configured all the variables.
4. python code is working fine with anaconda

I need to run the same code with the help of spark-submit command, the command is as below.

```
spark-submit examples/src/main/python/sql/streaming/structured_network_wordcount.py localhost 9999
```

But i am getting the below response.

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java" -cp "C:\Users\dharmendra.chaudhary\spark\spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.6\conf\;C:\Users\jack.smith\spark\spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.6\jars\*" -Xmx1g org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit examples/src/main/python/sql/streaming/structured_network_wordcount.py localhost 9999
```

The problem is that when I can the code with the help of Anaconda ide on the same machine, then what is the problem.